# Оптимизация выборки из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть две таблицы b_stat_city_ip (поля таблицы START_IP, END_IP, COUNTRY_ID, CITY_ID), b_stat_city (поля ID, COUNTRY_ID, REGION, NAME).
Необходимо получить ip адрес и узнать входит ли он в диапазон значений полей START_IP, END_IP, если да, то получить его COUNTRY_ID. Далее на основании COUNTRY_ID получить значения полей REGION, NAME.
Я написал следующий код, который полностью рабочий. Вопрос в том можно ли эту запись полностью оптимизировать? Если да то, как? Если нет, то почему?

```
$ipAddr = ip2long('какой-то ip');

$strSql = "
    SELECT
        START_IP, END_IP,
        COUNTRY_ID, CITY_ID
    FROM 
        b_stat_city_ip
    WHERE
        START_IP <= $ipAddr
    AND
        END_IP >= $ipAddr
";

$data = $DB->Query($strSql, false, $err_mess.__LINE__);

while( $arrData = $data -> Fetch() ){
    $cityID = $arrData["CITY_ID"];
}

$strSql2 = "
    SELECT
        ID, COUNTRY_ID,
        REGION, NAME            
    FROM 
        b_stat_city
    WHERE
        ID = $cityID
";

$data = $DB->Query($strSql2, false, $err_mess.__LINE__);

while( $arrData = $data -> Fetch() ){
    print_r($arrData);
}
```

Comment: 1. никаких while когда выбираешь 1 запрос. 2. вместо двух запросов ОДИН джойн. 3. Класс $DB выкинуть на помойку, использовать PDO

Comment: Добрый день. Непонятна цель двух разных запросов. Сделайте один запрос вида `Select .. from b_stat_city .. where ID in (select CITY_ID from b_stat_city_ip ...)`. Или через join.

Comment: @Deft, а можете в полном виде написать запрос? (для ясности)

Comment: оптимизация зависит в данном случае только от наличия индексов. смотрите explain и если там полный перебор больших таблиц то делайте составной индекс по полям start_ip, end_ip. Но и разумеется выборка одним запросом, вместо двух отдельных явно лучше, как сказал @Deft

Comment: Покажите определения для таблиц. `SHOW CREATE TABLE b_stat_city;` `SHOW CREATE TABLE b_stat_city_ip;`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gnd96k
https://prnt.sc/gnd2fg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос переделал до такого, может кому-нибудь пригодится :)

```
SELECT 
    city_ip.CITY_ID, city_ip.END_IP, city_ip.COUNTRY_ID,
    stat_city.ID, stat_city.COUNTRY_ID, stat_city.REGION, stat_city.NAME
FROM 
    b_stat_city_ip AS city_ip, b_stat_city AS stat_city
WHERE 
    city_ip.START_IP <= $ipAddr AND
    city_ip.END_IP   >= $ipAddr AND 
    stat_city.ID = city_ip.CITY_ID
```